# ImageMagick change canvas size

Tags: resize, imagemagick

I am converting transparent png's so that the images are always square, this part I have finally figured out but now the issue is that instead of overwriting the input file it is creating two new files appended with a "-0" and "-1".

So this command:

```
convert xc:transparent "07.png" -extent 77x77 -transparent white  "07.png"
```

Creates a file named:
07-0.png and 07-1.png

07-0.png is the new image size but is completely white

07-1.png is the correct image with a new size

Why is there 2 images being created? How do I get it to just overwrite 07.png?  Even if I specify a different output name it still creates 2 file with -0 and -1 appended.

Comment: FYI `mogrify` changes an image in-place (as opposed to saving to a new output file).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I just had to remove the xc:transparent option.